# How many numbers of 7 digits can we form in which "4" appears at least three times and "8" appears at least twice?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many numbers of $7$ digits can we form in which "4" appears at least three times and "8" appears at least twice?

Zero can't be the first digit.

I've thought about dividing the problem into cases but I was wondering if there's another way of solving it.

The cases would be when 4 and 8 appears: 3 and 2, 3 and 3, 3 and 4, 4 and 2, 4 and 3, 5 and 2 times, forming six cases in total.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have attempted.

Comment: +1 : for correctly enumerating the cases, which is definitely how I would attack the problem.  Now, all that you have to do, is take any specific case, and compute the number of ways that such a case can occur, find a pattern in the formula, and then apply the pattern to the other cases.  **Starter** intuition, which does not complete the computation for a specific case is that the idea that if you have $n$ slots, and you want to distribute exactly $r$ "4"s and $s$ "8"s in the slots, the number of ways that the slots can be arranged is $$\binom{n}{r} \times \binom{n-r}{s}.$$

Comment: Note that although there may be an elegant shortcut to the following - so what?  Within each case, because the left-most digit can **not** be $0$, you need to distinguish whether, re previous comment, the $(r + s)$ pertinent slots include the left-most *slot*.  As I say, there is probably a more elegant approach, but for a new student trying to solve it on his own - so what?

Comment: By the way, one potential shortcut is to allow the leftmost digit to be $0$, which streamlines the computation.  Then "rinse and repeat", where the leftmost digit is **assumed** to be $0$.  Then, simply subtract the 2nd computation from the 1st.